# Require order when mocking with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

foo.js:

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
const { createApiInstance } = require("./../utils/api");

const api = createApiInstance()

async function findFoo(name) {
  console.log({ api });
  const res = await api({
    method: "GET",
    url: `/bar`,
  })
}

module.exports = { findFoo }
```

utils.js

```
const axios = require("axios");

const createApiInstance = (params) => axios.create();

module.exports = {
  createApiInstance,
};
```

test.js

```
const apiWrapper = require("./../utils/api");
jest.mock("./../utils/api");

const { findFoo } = require("./foo");

describe("Foo", () => {
  describe("findFoo", () => {
    it("foos", async () => {
      const spy = jest
        .spyOn(apiWrapper, "createApiInstance")
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(jest.fn()));

      const res = await findFoo("foo");
      console.log(res);
      spy.mockRestore();
    });
  });
});
```

If I leave `const { findFoo } = require("./foo");` where it is, `api` gets logged as `undefined` within foo.js, but if i move `const { findFoo } = require("./foo");` to below the `const spy =` line, it works correctly.

Why does the mocking not seem to work in the above require ordering?

Comment: Because if you haven't set up the mock before you import the module that uses it, you haven't set it up before that module imports _and immediately uses_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said, you need to set up the mock return value of the `createApiInstance` function before requiring the `foo.js` module. Remember, the `createApiInstance` function will execute instantly when you require it. This means when you require a module the code defined in the module scope will be executed.

E.g.

`foo.js`:

```js
const { createApiInstance } = require("./api");

const api = createApiInstance()

async function findFoo(name) {
  console.log({ api });
  return api({
    method: "GET",
    url: `/bar`,
  })
}

module.exports = { findFoo }
```

`api.js`:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const createApiInstance = (params) => axios.create();

module.exports = {
  createApiInstance,
};
```

`foo.test.js`:

```js
const { createApiInstance } = require("./api");

jest.mock("./api");

describe("Foo", () => {
  describe("findFoo", () => {
    it("foos", async () => {
      expect(jest.isMockFunction(createApiInstance)).toBeTruthy();
      const mockApi = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test data');
      createApiInstance.mockReturnValueOnce(mockApi);
      const { findFoo } = require("./foo");
      const res = await findFoo("foo");
      expect(res).toEqual('test data');
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76064501/foo.test.js (6.537 s)
  Foo
    findFoo
      ✓ foos (15 ms)

  console.log
    {
      api: [Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
        getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    }

      at stackoverflow/76064501/foo.js:6:11

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.825 s, estimated 7 s
```